# r transform dataset from long to wide with all combinations

Tags: r, transform, reshape2

Assuming this is my dataset.

```
 Type   Drat  Qsec   Wt
 Mazda  3.9   16.46  2.620
 Toyota 3.85  17.02  2.875
 Ford   3.15  3.44   17.02
 Duster 3.21  15.84  18.3
```

I am interested in tranforming this dataset to a format like this

```
 Type.x   Drat.x  Qsec.x   Wt.x      Type.y  Drat.y  Qsec.y   Wt.y 
 Mazda    3.9     16.46    2.620     Toyota  3.85    17.02   2.875
 Mazda    3.9     16.46    2.620     Ford    3.15    3.44    17.02
 Mazda    3.9     16.46    2.620     Duster  3.21    15.84   18.3

 Toyota   3.85    17.02    2.875     Ford    3.15    3.44    17.02
 Toyota   3.85    17.02    2.875     Duster  3.21    15.84   18.3

 Ford     3.15    3.44     17.02     Duster  3.21    15.84   18.3
```

1st row - 2nd row

1st row - 3rd row

1st row - 4th row

2nd row - 3rd row

2nd row - 4th row

3rd row - 4th row

I am not exactly clear how to do this efficiently. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your dataframe is called `df`; I have created an example df like this:

```r
df <- mtcars[2:5,c("drat","qsec","wt")]
df$Type <- rownames(df)

> df
                  drat  qsec    wt              Type
Mazda RX4 Wag     3.90 17.02 2.875     Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710        3.85 18.61 2.320        Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive    3.08 19.44 3.215    Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout 3.15 17.02 3.440 Hornet Sportabout
```

We can use `dplyr` with a sequence of combinations, transformations, and joins.

```r
library(dplyr)

t(combn(df$Type,2)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(Type.x = V1,Type.y = V2) %>% 
  inner_join(df,by = c("Type.x" = "Type")) %>% 
  inner_join(df,by = c("Type.y" = "Type"))

          Type.x            Type.y drat.x qsec.x  wt.x drat.y qsec.y  wt.y
1  Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710   3.90  17.02 2.875   3.85  18.61 2.320
2  Mazda RX4 Wag    Hornet 4 Drive   3.90  17.02 2.875   3.08  19.44 3.215
3  Mazda RX4 Wag Hornet Sportabout   3.90  17.02 2.875   3.15  17.02 3.440
4     Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive   3.85  18.61 2.320   3.08  19.44 3.215
5     Datsun 710 Hornet Sportabout   3.85  18.61 2.320   3.15  17.02 3.440
6 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout   3.08  19.44 3.215   3.15  17.02 3.440
```